# How to add custom HTML attribute to reusable block div in Wordpress admin

Tags: filters, block-editor

So I'm trying to clarify when an editor is editing a reusable block in the WordPress admin.

For this, I would need to add a custom attribute title printed in the div of the reusable block in the WordPress admin.

I have found that I can change it a bit with this code, but it's just static and can't connect it to each rendered block:

```
add_filter( 'block_type_metadata', function ( $metadata ) {
    if ( 'core/block' === $metadata['name'] ) {
        $metadata['title'] = 'Reusable Block Title Test';
    }
    return $metadata;
});
```

I can't find any way to do something like `data-reusable-block-title="Product Slider for Global"`(this is the title of the reusable block) into the HTML as it's rendered via javascript.

How can I retrieve post title from a post ID of the reusable block and then input it in to a HTML attribute of the Gutenberg block being rendered by javascript and then use that attribute in CSS to create the styling that I would like?

I'm looking for a result something like this without needing to re-save every single page and store it in the block data somehow and retrieve it that way:

[image]

Thanks in advance!

Edit **

The answer I came up with which have some flaws:

**Flaws:**

- Makes a request per each reusable block on the page.
- Uses mutation observer instead of a `wp.hooks.onRenderBlock` hook. (Could not find documentation for this or anything like it)
- Uses REST instead of adding some filter that possibly could render this simple attribute.

PHP:

```
class ReusableBlockServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    public function register(): void
    {
        $this->registerRestRoutes();
        $this->enqueueScripts();
    }

    private function enqueueScripts(){
        add_action('admin_enqueue_scripts', function(){
            wp_enqueue_script( 'theme/admin/reusable-block', asset('scripts/gutenberg/reusableBlocks.js')->uri());
        });
    }

    private function registerRestRoutes(){
        add_action( 'rest_api_init', function(){
            register_rest_route( 'wp/v2', '/reusableBlock/(?P<id>\d+)', array(
                'methods' => 'GET',
                'args' => array(
                    'id' => array(
                        'validate_callback' => function($param, $request, $key) {
                            return is_numeric( $param );
                        }
                    ),
                ),
                'callback' => function(WP_REST_Request $req){
                    $params = $req->get_url_params();
                    if(empty($params['id'])){
                        return json_encode([
                            'success' => false,
                            'message' => 'ID not set'
                        ]);
                    }
                    $postId = $params['id'];
                    $post = get_post($postId);
                    $postLocaleData = apply_filters( 'wpml_post_language_details', null, $postId ) ;

                    return json_encode([
                        'postTitle' => $post->post_title,
                        'localeName' => $postLocaleData['display_name'],
                        'fullPostLocaleData' => $postLocaleData
                    ]);
                },
            ));
        });
    }
}
```

Javascript:

```
wp.domReady( () => {
  const gutenbergWrapperObserver = new MutationObserver(function (mutations) {
    mutations.forEach(function (mutation) {
      const foundNode = [...mutation.addedNodes].find((addedNode) => {
        return addedNode != null && addedNode.classList != null && addedNode.classList.contains('is-reusable') && addedNode.classList.contains('wp-block-block')
      })
      if(foundNode != null){
        wp.data.select('core/block-editor').getBlocks().filter((block) => { // Filter out reusable blocks only
          return block.name === 'core/block'
        }).forEach((block) => {
          wp.apiFetch( { path: `/wp/v2/reusableBlock/${block.attributes.ref}` } ).then( ( data ) => { // For each block retrieve data for it
            if(typeof data === 'string'){ // data come as string assume its json need to be parsed.
              data = JSON.parse(data)
            }
            const reusableBlock = document.querySelector(`[data-block="${block.clientId}"]`) // Look for reusable block in HTML
            if(reusableBlock != null){ // If found add extra attribute
              reusableBlock.setAttribute('data-reusable-block-title', `${data.postTitle} ${data.localeName}`)
            }
          } );
        })
      }
    });
  });
  const editorWrapper = document.getElementById('editor');
  if(editorWrapper){
    gutenbergWrapperObserver.observe(editorWrapper, { attributes: true, childList: true, subtree: true });
  }
} );
```